# How to get the next available menu item

Tags: menu

In my current active menu item, I want to get the next possible (enabled) menu item. Is there any coherent approach to do so?

**Update:**
Case:
I have a menu named English Menu
It has five items.

I am currently in item 1, and naturally the next item would be item 2. With such strategy in mind, I can create a nice navigational menu for pages (apart from main navigation) like this:

Next Page (Item 2)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more of what you are trying to achieve? Put some more context in your question.

Comment: @FFrewin updated

Comment: Hi. It's very hard to understand you question. You are talking about a <ul> menu, sub menu or what?Do you want to target menu items with CSS?

Comment: @Mike Fitzpatrick, Please don't confuse client and server. I'm talking about Menu Records saved in the database. Forget about client side.  I just gave the client example to clarify things further, which nevertheless, has resulted the otherwise.

Comment: Still not sure I get the question - do you simply want a next article / previous article on each page so users can go back and forward?

Answer (score 2):

You could get the next item using the lft and rgt fields simply by getting the first item with a higher lft value than your current item's rgt value, and only selecting published items.

```
SELECT *
FROM #_menu
WHERE menutype LIKE 'your_menu'
AND published = 1
AND lft > [current item rgt]
ORDER BY lft ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Depending on if you want to include items from other levels of your menu you might want to add an "AND level = [your current item's level]".